# Dequeue iterator not dereferencable

Tags: c++, stack

Through doing a little research online, I've found that this is error is caused by trying to pop something off an empty stack. In my code, I thought I tried to make sure this exact thing wouldn't happen by storing the top of my stack in a temporary string called `c`, but for some reason the error keeps occurring. This is a project related to converting infix notation to postfix notation. When I input `1+2+3`, I should get `12+3+`, but instead this error occurs. The error occurs in the precedence while loop.

```
stack <string> InfixToPostfix(char * expr)
{
  // YOUR CODE STARTS HERE! 
 char* token;
 stack<string> s;
 string postfix;
 stack<string> p;
                                     // use stack s to manipulate the infix      to postfix
 s.push("(");
  token = strtok (expr," "); // get the first token
  while(!s.empty())
  {
          if(token=="(")
        {
            s.push(token);
          }
         else if(token==")")
      {
            string c=s.top();
            s.pop();
             while(c != "(")
            {
            postfix += c + " ";
            c = s.top();
            s.pop();
        }
  }
  else if(isNumber(token))
  {
      postfix+=token;
  }
  else 
  {
      while(precedence(s.top())>=precedence(token))
      {
          //put on bottom if need be

           string c = s.top();
            s.pop();
            postfix += c;
            postfix += " ";
      }
      s.push(token);
  }

token = strtok(NULL, " "); // use blanks as delimiter
  if (token == NULL) // no more tokens, exit the loop
     break;
  }
  p.push(postfix);
  return p;
}
```

Comment: Why dont you just use  .empty() method to check if your stack is empty ?

Comment: How so? Wouldn't the condition I put in my outer while loop cover that?

Comment: you should always check if your stack is empty before poping an element. You dont do that in your if statements

Comment: My entire while loop only functions if the stack isn't empty though. Adding that condition in an if statement hasn't helped as of yet. I do very much appreciate your response though. Any help I can get is good help because this error is frustrating

Comment: @Gary `if(token=="(")`  This is not how you compare C-style strings.  Your entire code is flawed due to this issue.  Use `strcmp`.

Comment: @Paul, thank you. I don't know much about C-style strings, but making these changes helped my code run. Along with one more unrelated change.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the if statements within the main while loop, you have some calls to `pop()` without checking if the deque is empty for example

```
 while(c != "(") {
     postfix += c + " ";
     c = s.top();
     s.pop();
 }
```

This should probably be:

```
while(c != "(" && !s.empty()) {

}
```

And the same below

```
while(precedence(s.top())>=precedence(token))
{
      //put on bottom if need be
      string c = s.top();
      s.pop();
      postfix += c;
      postfix += " ";
 }
 s.push(token);
```

These are quite likely sources of invalid access. In general you should try to use `gdb` or `valgrind --tool=memcheck` which will show you the source of error. Or any other debugger really...

Also if the token is a single character as I suspect it should be, make it a `char` not a `char *`. Then in your token comparisons use `token == ')'` (note the single quotes) which compares two *characters* and not what you have now which compares a char pointer with a string literal... This will probably apply to all the data structures that you maintain as well which should become, e.g. `deque<char> ...`

Finally pick up [any decent introductory C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) book and read it. You will thank yourself later.